# multiple jquery toggles on one page

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hi I'm trying to get multiple instances of a jquery toggle working on a single page, using divs. Current fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sketch360/kX34v/  and I am using the simple javascript:

```
$(".toggle-title").click(function () {
    $(".toggle-details").toggle("fast");
});
```

Unfortunately at the moment, toggling any of the headings shows all of the results, as obviously they all carry the same class, but I can't find a way of just activating the child div belonging to its parent, without also activating the other children.

I'm trying to find a way of doing this without having to modify the html too much, ie having different classes for each of the children.

I've already looked at Jeff's answer: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYPWN) and whilst it works fine in the fiddle, it doesn't seem to work within my (wordpress) site. My fiddle above is working, just without the independent toggle action that I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do it that way. You toggle everything that way. So, change your code this way:

```
$(".toggle-title").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".toggle-details").toggle("fast");
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/kX34v/1/

Comment: Thankyou so much Praveen, that's really helpful - worked straight away - THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Following one also work if you use jquery 1.2 or later version

```
$(".toggle-title").click(function () {        
     $(this).nextAll(".toggle-details").first().toggle("fast");
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kX34v/3/